# Calculate position from top of div

Tags: javascript

So I have a div with a height and a width, when I hover over it I want to calculate the distance between mouse and top of div and also left of div, how can I achieve this using javascript ?

Comment: No, this is asking about relative mouse positions

Comment: I researched a lot....

Comment: Please share the results of your research, why it didn't work in your case, what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document.body).mousemove(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $("#div").offset(); 
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

});
```

Comment: you are a damn genius, thanks man, it worked !!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery event pageX and pageY and the div properties offset().left and offset().top.
And juste make the subtraction.